# Add dynamic shapes in the image using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the dynamic shapes like circle, rectangle, line, oval, etc in the image using jquery plugin or javascript. For ex:

[image]

In this image dynamic text can be create by write in textbox somewhat this type of same I want do for add the shape

I have research it in different software website but there is noting appropriate result has come. Please give me some hint to solve this problem.

for demo you can refer the following link

http://www.printo.in => http://www.printo.in/translucent-cards-single-sided-translucent-card-ss-blank-4552

http://www.vistaprint.in => http://www.vistaprint.in/studio.aspx?template=471103%7es1_AHT_023&ag=True

Advance in thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 `<canvas></canvas>` element.

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 70;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();

      //On mouse events on the canvas
      $canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
        lastEvent = e;
        mousedown = true;
      }).mousemove(function(e) {
      //Draw lines
      if(mousedown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastEvent.offsetX, lastEvent.offsetY);
        ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();
        lastEvent = e;
      }
    }).mouseup(function() {
      mousedown = false;
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      $canvas.mouseup();
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But how can I draw in the image? And this is possible to do in div. Because for dynamic text I have done in div only. Like this <div id="container"> </div> So the text is coming by the fetch the id of the div.

Comment: And also I want dynamic not a static

Comment: @s.k.Soni You can't draw "in the image" with JavaScript (such that, for example, a user could right click > save image as and get the result of your drawing). But a canvas will give you an area you can draw on with JS, including using an image for the background.

Comment: I am not telling that iwant to do from JavaScript only... It can also be done from jquery.  As per you see the link it can be done by jquery and also JavaScript.  So this type of image editing i want.